# Display 'modified date' in Wordpress Twenty Fourteen

Tags: date, theme-twenty-fourteen

Could anyone tell me how I can show the modified date from posts to my readers? I use Wordpress Twenty Fourteen with the Twenty Fourteen Extended plugin. Structured Data testing Tool already shows this code so I think this should be alright for rich snippets:

```
<meta property="article:modified_time" content="2015-08-18T17:48:22+00:00" />
<meta property="og:updated_time" content="2015-08-18T17:48:22+00:00" />
```

But only the publised date is shown on my site.

Comment: One question per post please. You can ask your other question as a new question. Please see [ask] and [help] :-)

Answer (score 0):

Look for the code that displays the post date. It should look something like the following:

```
Posted on: <?php the_time('l, F jS, Y') ?>
```

Now replace it with the following code (slightly modified from [Ardamis’ post](http://wordpressgeekhelp.blogspot.com/2015/08/how-to-showing-last-modified-date-on.html)):
Posted on

```
<?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?>
<?php $u_time = get_the_time('U');
$u_modified_time = get_the_modified_time('U');
if ($u_modified_time != $u_time) {
echo "and last modified on ";
the_modified_time('F jS, Y');
echo ". "; } ?>
```

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks, but in which file can I find that code? It isn't in content.php, single.php or template-tags.php

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks, but in which file can I find that code? It isn't in content.php, single.php or template-tags.php In template tags there is this code     <pre> printf( '<span class="entry-date"><a href="%1$s" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date" datetime="%2$s">%3$s</time></a></span> <span class="byline"><span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="%4$s" rel="author">%5$s</a></span></span>',
  esc_url( get_permalink() ),
  esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
  esc_html( get_the_date() ),
  esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ),
  get_the_author()
 );
<code>